# HTML: Download link "Failed to load PDF"

Tags: html, pdf

I am trying to allow my webpage to host pdf to be downloaded from my server. When you click the link, it downloads a file, but the file it downloads does not open. In Adobe it says "it is either not a supported file type or the file has been damaged". In chrome it says the file failed to load.

I know the file is not corrupted because I can open the file just fine in WINSCP (FTP client). Online the code seems very simple yet it is not working for me.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <a href ="/documents/Cow.pdf" download>Download</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

The cow.pdf is stored in a folder named documents. The document folder is saved in a folder named template, where all my other HTML pages are saved.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What if instead you used the full path of the pdf instead of a relative path?

Comment: I've been told that is bad practice..thats is why i've been trying to avoid it. The website will be moved to a more stable sever after everything is done

Comment: Right, it is, but for testing purposes... if you use the full link does it work properly? It could be that your link is just pointing to the wrong location

Comment: looks like download is written twice.  change to  <a href ="/documents/Cow.pdf" >Download</a>
*add target='_blank'   to get it to open in a new window so the user doesn't leave your website on download.

Comment: @Adjit I put in the absolute file location, and I get the same error...Ideas?

Comment: @Cameron Without that first download, it doesnt try to download a file, it just tries to open a page in webpage then says the page doesn't exist

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a fiddle? So we can test what is going on. It could be the server, but I'm not sure. Or the compatibility of the PDF file. Have you tried a different PDF file?

Comment: can you put an image in the same folder and try to reference it using the same path?  try something like..
.
    <img src="/documents/your-image.jpg" alt="">   

are you running it locally or on the actual server? if its saying page does not exist I suspect the path is not correct.
What does the link url say if you right click and copy link location from the actual rendered html via the browser?